# bigcommerce api, how do I push multiple category ids when updating a product

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I'm using php to communicate with the bigcommerce API and I can update a product's category, by pushing the following:

```
'categories' => "['value']  = 10",
```

Maybe I am an idiot, or haven't attempted every possibility yet, but I have not figured out how to update and item with multiple categories.

I have attempted to send and array of associative arrays, to no avail.

thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: what's the code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

disregard, bigcommerce is a odd bird.

my free solution:

to add one category, you'll push:

```
"categories" => (array("value"=>$myCategoryID)),
```

but for multiple:

```
"categories" => ($myCategories),
```

where $myCategories=explode(',','id,id,id,id');

I apologize for answering my own question again, but it seems that I am the only person on earth developing a bigcommerce app these days....

lol(i laugh cause crying doesn't help)